# Does that series converge or does the one diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^3 $$ with $x_1=\pi/4$ and $x_{n+1}=\arctan(x_n)$ converge or diverge?

Comment: I think about that.

Comment: Thinking about it is nice but I would enjoy knowing what you have tried up to now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0<\arctan x<x$ for all $x>0$ you can show that $x_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$. Hence using Taylor series of $\arctan x$ we get that $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{1}{3}x_n^3(1+\varphi_n)$ for some sequence $\varphi_n$ converging to $0$. There exist a natural number $N$ such that $|\varphi_n|<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n>N$. Therefore
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty x_n^3
=6\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{3}x_n^3\frac{1}{2}
\leq 6\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{3}x_n^3(1+\varphi_n)
=6\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n-x_{n+1})-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{3}x_n^3(1+\varphi_n)\right)
=6\left(x_1-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{3}x_n^3(1+\varphi_n)\right)<\infty
$$
Hence the series inquestion is converges.

Comment: Could you explain why $$ 6\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{3}x_n^3\frac{1}{2}
\leq 6\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{3}x_n^3(1+\varphi_n)$$  holds in view of $|\varphi_n|<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{2}\leq 1+\varphi_n$ and $x_n>0$

Comment: I accept your answer. However, I don't see how to investigate the convergence or divergence of $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^{5/2}$$ in this way.

Comment: In this case you need to know the exact asymptotics of $x_n$. You should ask this as separate question. By the way I know the solution :)

Comment: It is a real pleasure  for me to consort with you. Please replace $\infty$ by $0$ in the first line.